# AJAX Cart - Best way to implement in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a PHP e-commerce site which stores the users cart in a session variable. I want to be able to manipulate this via AJAX using jQuery but I'm unsure of the best approach.

I think that I essentially want to create an API for the cart which I can then use throughout the system. For example, I would like to be able to do the following:

```
Cart.addItem(product_id, qty);
Cart.removeItem(product_id);
Cart.getTotal();
```

Behind the scenes this would make various AJAX requests to the server, updating the session as needed:

```
var Cart = {
    addItem: function(product_id, qty){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { product_id: product_id, qty: qty },
            url: 'cartAjax.php?action=add_to_cart',                
            success: function(){
               return true;
            }
        });
    },
    removeItem: function(product_id){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { product_id: product_id },
            url: 'cartAjax.php?action=remove_from_cart',                
            success: function(){
               return true;
            }
        });
    },
    getTotal: function(){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',                
            url: 'cartAjax.php?action=fetch_cart_total',                
            success: function(response){
               return response.total;
            }
         });
    }
}
```

Would this be the correct way to do it? Am I anywhere close to how this should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have gone a little careless in your response status, if  I were you, I would have done this:

```
var cartUpdatedInfo; // IMPORTANT
var Cart = {
    addItem: function(product_id, qty){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { product_id: product_id, qty: qty },
            dataType : 'json',
            url: 'cartAjax.php?action=add_to_cart',                
            success: function(data){
               if(data.result == 'DONE')
               {
                   cartUpdatedInfo = data.cartUpdatedInfo; // receives fresh data from server
               }
            }

           error : function(){
              // handle the error. VERY VERY IMPORTANT, to avoid scrip-level
              // errors to be exposed to the user
           }
        });
    },
 // the rest of the code
```

And in PHP, after doing the operation, I would have returned this:

```
/// operation done
if($operationDoneSuccessfully)
{
   // though you probably want to use echo
   return json_encode(array('result'=>'DONE', 'cartUpdatedInfo' => $cartInfo)); 
}
```

Using the above, you can update the cart info (or validate the client changes to), with the fresh valid data sent by server.

Also, it is worth to limit the user for one-click/request, which means that you'd better set a disabling-function for the click-event of the addToCart button, which means:

```
$("#addToCart").on("click", function(){
     // after doing certain things for prpation
     var cartBtn = $(this);
     setTimeout(function(){
         cartBtn.prop("disabled", true);
     }, 200);
});
```

And you can later, after your ajax finishes, re-enable it.

Another point on checking the request concurrency and/or their validity, you can add another param in your AJAX name something like "token" or "_token" or anything you like:

```
$.ajax({
   data : { token : randId(25) /* ..... */ },
   // the rest
});
```

and randId() function could be something like this:

```
function randId(len)
{
  var newNum = "";
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
     newNum += getRandomInt(0,9);
  }
  return newNum;
}
```

You may add an arbitary value to the beginning of the generated randomness, which allows you to ensure that is your own randomly generated token:

```
function randId(len)
{
  var newNum = "";
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
     newNum += getRandomInt(0,9);
  }
  return "token"+newNum;
}

// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (excluded)
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
} // Copied from MDN Javascript Documentation
```

I have treated the numbers as string to avoid memory allocation for large integers.

An extra note, do several things to boost your AJAX in the server-side:

- Set sessions to limit concurrent requests for the same URL by the
  user.
- Check user id or session each time for each individual task
- Always consider the user as person who is doing some tricks to
  change    the inputs sent by your AJAX

Comment: Good to see it helpful